# Where is the right place for this sort of logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am doing teach-yourself MVC, and have come up against a difficulty. My database has a table for Beers, and a table for Breweries. Naturally there is a foreign key constraint to ensure a Beer has a Brewery. This constraint is a "no action" constraint, intended to prevent a Brewery from being deleted if there are Beers for that Brewery in the database.

I am implementing the Index page for the Breweries, and the automatically-generated code lists the Breweries along with Edit, Details and Delete. So far, so good. If an attempt is made to delete a Brewery that has Beers, the delete fails owing to the foreign key constraint.

But it seems better to withhold the delete option when it can't succeed. This leads to code in the View like this:-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BreweryID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BreweryID })
@if(item.Beers.Count == 0)
{
    <text> |</text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.BreweryID })
}
```

It seems to me that the Model design is leaking out into the View, but I can't see any alternative; the Delete link must be displayed or not and the view has to do this.

How ought this sort of thing be tackled?

Comment: Note that in MVC, your views are tightly coupled to the defined models, thus leveraging a model's definition in its associated views is standard practice.

Comment: Indeed. That's the entire point of having a strongly-typed model in the first place. There's nothing wrong with the view interacting with the model. That's what it's *supposed* to do. You just want to watch out for excess logic in your view. Simply getting a count of the collection is no problem, but if you find yourself doing things like adding `Where` clauses `Selects`, etc. that's stuff that should be shuffled into the model class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is hardly a problem with 'leaking'. If the View needs certain data, and that data is available in the Model, then there really is no problem to access the data. It is a very common thing.

Still, if you'd rather not access the `.Beers` collection in the View, then you could add a property `bool HasBeers` to the `Brewery` ViewModel. You can then set that property in the Controller and use it in the View, so the View does not access more info than you want it to access.

Example code:

```
public class BreweryViewModel
{
    public bool HasBeers { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class BreweryController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var breweryVM = ...
        var beers = ...

        breweryVM.HasBeers = beers.Any();

        return View(breweryVM);
    }
}
```